# Loop over a table in Access vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, for-loop, vba

I have a for loop in access that goes from 1 to the count of the records in the table.  I want  to loop over and basically say if the first word of the client name is the same as the one before it to give it the same internal ID as the one before it but I am unsure how to reference the records using the index.  I am going to use the mid function to extract the part of the name I want to compare. I am rather new to VBA in Access so any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted what I have so far below.

```
Sub RevH()
Dim dte As String, clientQry As String, db As Database, clientTable As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb


dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")


clientQry = "SELECT DISTINCT t.[CLIENT ID], t.[CLIENT NAME] " & _
            "INTO Clients " & _
            "FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte & " as t WHERE " & _
            "((t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""*Test*"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""*Demo*"") AND ( t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""*Client*"" )AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Tufts"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""SCAN"" ) AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""US Script"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Care1st Health Plan"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""PBM View"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME]Not Like ""ScriptGuideRx"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Argus"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Centene"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""MMIT-FN - FormularyEditor"")  AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""CVS Caremark"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Caterpiller"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Horizon BCBS"") AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""Health Net"")  AND (t.[CLIENT NAME] Not Like ""CMS"")) " & _
            "ORDER BY [CLIENT NAME]"


If TableExists("Clients") Then
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete ("Clients")
End If

CurrentDb.Execute clientQry


DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE Clients ADD COLUMN [Internal_ID] DOUBLE;"

Set clientTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Clients")


For i = 1 To DCount("[CLIENT NAME]", "Clients")



Next i





End Sub
```

Comment: Are you also [user4095610](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4095610/user4095610)?

Comment: No? Why would you ask?

Comment: The text of `clientQry` gave me a sense of deja vu.

Comment: Well I'm not that user. Do you think you could help me with this?

Comment: Please first check whether bodjo already gave you what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead of for loop.

```
Dim intID As Integer
Dim sName As String

intID = 0
sName = vbNullstring
If Not clientTable.EOF And Not clientTable.BOF Then
  clientTable.MoveFirst
  Do While Not clientTable.EOF

    --apply your name comparison logic
    If sName <> Left(clientTable("[Client Name]"),5) Then
        sName = Left(clientTable("[Client Name]"),5)
        intID = intID + 1
    End If
    clientTable.Edit
    clientTable("[Internal_ID]") = intID
    clientTable.Update
    clientTable.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

Comment: It is doing almost what I want.  What is sName first initialized to?

Comment: sName initial value is blank. You can set sName = vbNullstring or you can keep it as is.

Comment: How would I modify to compare just the first 5 letters instead of the whole string? Could I implement the `mid` function for that?

Comment: I've modified my answer with name comparison of the first 5 letters.